# Django: POST data to specific URL

Tags: django

I'm sorry if this is a bit of a noob question - I'm just learning Django and I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

On one page, I have a form which returns a date-time object.

I want to then validate the user's POST, and re-direct them to a page with the following format: `/'YYYY-MM-DD'/`

I have everything working except the redirect. What I'm thinking is the best way would be to manually redirect them to the new URL, and use a URL pattern such as this `url(r'^application/?P<deadline_date>(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}), ... )'` to get them to the page I want. Maybe there's a better way?

If not, how can I redirect them to a custom URL? I have looked at the docs, but the way `redirect` works is not clear to me at all: if I have a date string in the format `'DD-MM-YYY'` inside a view as a result of a POST to `URL`, how do I get users to `URL/DD-MM-YYYY`?

I have tried this:

if request.method == "POST":
    date_form = DateForm(request.POST)

```
if date_form.is_valid():
    datetimedate = date_form.cleaned_data["date"]
    date_str = datetimedate.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    url = '{}/'.format(date_str)
    redirect('http://localhost:8000/courtapptimeline/application/' + url)
```

and this:

if request.method == "POST":
    date_form = DateForm(request.POST)

```
if date_form.is_valid():
    datetimedate = date_form.cleaned_data["date"]
    date_str = datetimedate.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    url = '{}/'.format(date_str)
    redirect(url)
```

but both redirect to my base `URL`.

Comment: Redirect is always done manually. I'm not sure what difficulties do you have. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: Your url pattern is wrong: `(?P<deadline_date>\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4})` (`?P` should appear just after `(`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to **return** as such:

`return redirect('http://localhost:8000/courtapptimeline/application/{0}'.format(url))`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I had to return.